# LibVncClient get operation system info

Tags: c++, c, client, vnc, rfb-protocol

I use the libvncclient, to build a viewer, in which i try to integrate a specific hotkeys which do a bit of scripting, that are done as menu options, such as `enable taskmanager`,'run cmd' for window, and 'open terminal,'update repos' etc. I need to detect the operating system info, but i don't see anything to get this info from in rfb proto

```
rfbClient *client = new client();

if(!ConnectToRFBServer(client,client->serverHost,client->serverPort))
      return FALSE;
    
if (!InitialiseRFBConnection(client))
     return FALSE;
```

I looked trough the `rfbclient.h` and rfbClient structure doesn't hold any callback/or field that stores this info, as well as there is no apis for that it seems. But in rfc there is this thing https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6143#section-7.3.2

**After receiving the ClientInit message, the server sends a ServerInit
message.  This tells the client the width and height of the server's
framebuffer, its pixel format, and the name associated with the
desktop:**

Richardson & Levine           Informational                    [Page 11]

RFC 6143             The Remote Framebuffer Protocol          March 2011

```
  +--------------+--------------+------------------------------+
  | No. of bytes | Type [Value] | Description                  |
  +--------------+--------------+------------------------------+
  | 2            | U16          | framebuffer-width in pixels  |
  | 2            | U16          | framebuffer-height in pixels |
  | 16           | PIXEL_FORMAT | server-pixel-format          |
  | 4            | U32          | name-length                  |
  | name-length  | U8 array     | name-string                  |
  +--------------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

But it seems that libvnc doesn't handle that, is there any way that this info could be taken?